# expect - expect_out comparison

Tags: tcl, expect

I have input from remote device that I want to catch and based on it to execute some commands - the script is working fine! but  there is one problem - expect is looping through each line (with exp_continue) and when find a REGEX match is executing some commands based on the match ($expect_out).. works fine.., but is literally based on every line! :( and I want somehow to compare $expect_out(n,string) with other previous and futures matches and execute ONLY one commands based on the unique match.

Maybe is simpler to give the example:

The input contains: "1/1/1" and "1/1/2" duplicated strings, but on different lines and I catch them and executing duplicated commands based on them :(

Input:

```
VL.  Interface
-----------------------
10   vlanIf:1/1/1:10
20   vlanIf:1/1/3:20
30   vlanIf:1/1/2:30
40   vlanIf:1/1/4:40
50   vlanIf:1/1/2:50
60   vlanIf:1/1/1:60
70   vlanIf:1/1/1:70
```

Script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -f
  telnet ...
  ---snipped--
  set prompt "#"

# cmd1
  expect "$prompt" { send "show interface vlan\r" ; set is_ok "cmd1" }
    if { $is_ok != "cmd1" } { send_user "\n## #----- 9 Exit on executing command3\n" ; exit }

# cmd2 ... n
  expect -re "(vlanIf:)(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+):(\\d\{1,4\})" {
    set secondMatch "$expect_out(2,string)" 
    send "show test1 $secondMatch\r"
    send "show test2 $secondMatch\r"
    send "show test3 $secondMatch\r"
    exp_continue
  }
```

In My attempt result is:

```
  send "show test1 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/1\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/3\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/3\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/3\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/2\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/4\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/4\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/4\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/2\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/1\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/1\r"
```

Results should be:

```
  send "show test1 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/1\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/1\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/3\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/3\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/3\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/2\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/2\r"

  send "show test1 1/1/4\r"
  send "show test2 1/1/4\r"
  send "show test3 1/1/4\r"
```

*1/1/1, 1/1/3, 1/1/2, 1/1/4 are variables but for the example I put content:

Comment: What are you _actually_ getting?

Comment: I added: In My attempt result is:

Comment: If I can re-paraphrase I would say: I need to write output from expect command to variable or file - and then to pipe (|) this output for example with " | uniq "  and then to return the result in other variable or file (and the tricky part is to made that in one telnet session to device not two :D )

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer that's work for me :)

It's pretty easy actually.

```
...
if [regexp $secondMatch $secondMatchSTACKED] {
  exp_continue
} else {
...
send "show test1 $secondMatch\r"
send "show test2 $secondMatch\r"
send "show test3 $secondMatch\r"
set secondMatchSTACKED "$secondMatchSTACKED$secondMatch "
exp_continue
```